# How to evaluate struts 2 s:property if property have double or single quote?

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have one property called **test** in my action class.This property can have single or double quotes with some string value.

My Struts2 Action Class code

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport  {

  private String test; //With Getter Method.

  @Override
  public String execute() throws Exception {
      test = //getting value from database (for example - hello' stackoverflow)
      return SUCCESS;
  }


}
```

struts.xml code

```
    <action name="actionCall" class="MyAction">
        <result name="success">SuccessPage.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

SuccessPage.jsp

```
<s:property value="test"/>
```

when I am trying to print it on jsp page by struts2 property tag

```
<s:property value="test"/> or <s:property value='test'/>
```

it is not printing complete value. For example

**case 1.**

if test = hello' stackoverflow

then it is printing **hello** only, because of single quote (if I use `<s:property value='test'/>`)

**case 2.**

if test = hello" stackoverflow

then it is printing **hello** only, because of double quote (if I use `<s:property value="test"/>`)

How do I print complete value on jsp page ?

Comment: You don't have any property, if you have one post it here.

Comment: @AnkitSharma: this doesn't make any sense. If you have `String test = "blabla ' blabla \" blabla "`, `<s:property value="test" />` will print out `blabla ' blabla " blabla`. There is something you are not saying to us.

Comment: How do you set value to this property?

Comment: In what context are you "printing" it? If it's just in HTML and you use the `<s:property>` tag it will print just fine. If you're attempting to embed it in JavaScript then you'd obviously need to JS-escape it. I'm with Andrea, there's missing information.

Comment: I hv updated my question, please check

Comment: Try to assign this string directly to `test` and see if this works. Also which version of S2 are you using?

Comment: My struts version is 2.3.7. I tried direct value too. I am completely stuck here :(

Comment: @AnkitSharma Please provide the exact JSP code and values. The contents of the string when regarding quotes is irrelevant; quotes do not need to be escaped to be displayed via an S2 tag in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

email.jsp page

```
   <form action="call_Myaction_class">
       <input type="text" name="email"/>
   </form>
```

Myaction.class

```
public class Myaction extends ActionSupport  {

   private String email;//Getter and Setter Method.

  @Override
  public String execute() throws Exception {

    HttpServletRequest request=(HttpServletRequest) ActionContext.getContext().get(ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);

    setEmail("mailid@gmail.com");

  }

}
```

struts.xml

```
    <action name="call_Myaction_class" class="Myaction">
          <result name="error">error.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">success.jsp</result>
     </action>
```

success.jsp

```
<s:property value="email"/>
```